# Is there any difference between the two prononciations, /ˈter-ə-bəl/ and /ˈte-rə-bəl/, showed in the picture?

Tags: pronunciation, syllables

For the word terrible, there are two different ways to pronounce it on Merriam-Webster:

> ter·​ri·​ble | \ ˈter-ə-bəl, ˈte-rə- \

And this question has been confusing me for a very long time. When the R-controlled vowel followed by a vowel in a word, should we pronounce the R-controlled vowel as in the same syllable or the r sound should be pronounced with the vowel after it?

Comment: The video sounds close to tur-ble (tur rhyming with fur, and two syllables or with an almost non existent middle syllable.  There are some people who pronounce it like that, but the "correct" and common pronunciation is te-ri-ble.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IhMUmNfZGkA

Comment: There is considerable variation in how "terrible" is pronounced by English speakers.  It's one of the things my wife teases me about, since I habitually say "*tur-ble*" not "*ter-ri-bull*".  However, it would be considered good diction to clearly enunciate the double "r" sound, and not swallow the second syllable.

Comment: I have explained it in detail in an [answer to your previous question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/272849/106592). According to MOP, it should be **/te.rə.bəl/** not ***/ter.ə.bəl/**.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, Merriam-Webster provides a "[Guide to Pronunciation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/assets/mw/static/pdf/help/guide-to-pronunciation.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjEq8Cv0K_uAhVBZMAKHQCJDUkQFjAAegQIAxAC&usg=AOvVaw3vWJOR7xZrG1vgJI7qlv9O)" (PDF) (linked from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/help)), which explains all of its notations with additional information. Salient points from that guide:

- Not all dialects allow \e-r\; speakers of some dialects have \er\ even in words where Merriam-Webster gives \e-r\. This means that in some dialects, the two listed pronunciations are actually the same.
- \e-r\ denotes the vowel \e\ (as in *bet*) plus the consonant \r\ (as in *red*).
- \er\ denotes a diphthong where the first part can be anywhere from \e\ (as in *bet*) to \ā\ (as in *day*) and the second part is \ər\ (as in *singer*).

Neither listed pronunciation is the one that fixer1234 and Andrew mention, where the *terr-* is pronounced as in *terrific* or *terrarium*. Maybe Merriam-Webster needs to add that one!